# what does this java code mean

Tags: java, syntax

I came across the following code and am a bit confused.

```
LocalConfig conf = new LocalConfig() {
  @Override
  public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(String name) {
    return new AppConfigurationEntry[] {
        new AppConfigurationEntry(moduleName(),
            AppConfigurationEntry.LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUIRED,
            put("principal", RPCConstants.DOMAINUSER).
            put("useTicketCache","true").
            build())
    };
  }
};
```

There is a code block after  `LocalConfig conf = new LocalConfig()` without a semi-colon.. Since `LocalConfig` is invoked with a `new` I am not sure how this block after `LocalConfig` is processed by compiler. Appreciate insights.

Comment: That's an anonymous inner class. It's a class that implements or extends LocalConfig but the new class itself has no name.

Comment: Hm. 6 answers in less than a minute? And all seem to be (at least almost) correct? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an anonymous class. `LocalConfig` is probably an interface that requires an implementation for `public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(String name)`. This is just a short-hand way of creating an ad-hoc implementation of the interface. The usual way is to create a concrete implementation which resides in its own `.java` file.

Here you are providing an ad-hoc implementation and then assigning it to the variable `conf`.

For example, assume you had an interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    int foo(String bar);
}
```

Typically you would create an implementation (especially if you expect this concrete implementation to have a lot of logic and to be re-used heavily):

```
public class MyInterfaceImplementation implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public int foo(String bar) {
        ...
        return someIntVar;
    }        
}
```

Then you would instantiate it using `MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterfaceImplementation();`. Instead of doing that, you can create an ad-hoc implementation like this:

```
MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterface() {
    @Override
    public int foo(String bar) {
        ...
        return someIntVar;
    }
}
```

Some people eschew the use of all and any anonymous classes. I think it depends on the user-case. If the interface is simple (like an event handler) and unlikely to be reused, then I think an inner class is fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is and anonymous class, as LocalConfig is interface there need be an implementation of it.
So when you instantiate you should have an implementation but as you dont have it you create on the fly.

You use this approach when you dont want to create a reusable own implementation an just cover an specific case or solution. Also this are very useful in GUI approach

Answer (score 1):

It's called an anonymous class - you instantiate an object of a non-existent class "on the fly" without persisting it as a class and are able to overwrite/implement abstract methods on the spot.

Answer (score 1):

This is an anonymous class.  It is defining a class which extends/implements `LocalConfig` without giving it a name, instantiating that class and assigning it to a variable called `conf`.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can override Classes (or implement interface) on-the-fly if you only need that specific subclass class once. This is what the code does: It creates a new instance of `LocalConfig` but extends it (in this case, overrriding `getAppCOnfigurationEntry()`.